# Books recommended for a beginner SharePoint architect

Tags: sharepoint, architecture, sharepoint-2010

I am a recent graduate and got a job as a junior SharePoint developer few months ago. For the last few months, I have been working on SharePoint development, e.g. webparts, .Net Forms, K2, Lists, Features, for Moss and a little bit for SharePoint 2010 as well...

Now because I made a future plan to become a SharePoint architect, I am not sure what way I need to follow to become what I want to, As there are so many things to learn in SharePoint, I am looking for Book or a series of Book that will help me gain knowledge as a SharePoint Architect has.

I am a bit confused with SharePoint architecture as well, like If I want to develop a new SharePoint Solution, What hardware e.g. Servers, Do I need + Software, e.g. We use .Net Forms, but are they better then using Info-Path forms ?

Thanks (*I know its not a Coding question but I think its somehow related to Programming so please dont close it..* Cheers)

Comment: i think you can gain knowledge on a platform but to answer the kind of questions you are asking you really just need experience. Also keep up with the blogs of people who are at the top of the field. They are likely to have some great info. Andrew Connell is one guy ive found has a pretty good blog on SharePoint.

Comment: Another thing you can look at it http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or look at programmers.stackexchange.com, where a similar question has also beem asked. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/72880/where-can-i-find-resources-for-learning-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a huge amount to learn in order to "become" an architect for SharePoint. Do not forget that you will need to learn how the SharePoint content database works, especially how documents are stored. You will also need to figure out the infrastructure part of the equation, especially how virtualised environments will affect server performance.

Essentially, there is not enough space to list all the books that could be useful.

You have set yourself a long term task, so go hard with the curiosity. Whenever you run across a subject that you do not know the details of, hit google and find out.

For example, the difference between .NET forms and Info path forms maybe available in a book, but you are going to learn more quickly and thoroughly by creating some Infopath forms and having a look at how both are implemented.

There is no real shortcut around the hard graft required to learn SharePoint (except perhaps finding someone who already is good at this and learning from them directly).

Answer (score 1):

A free ebook downlodable from msdn :
Developing Applications for SharePoint 2010
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx
It's a good starting point.